# Custom SharePoint Template not showing up on Sub-Site

Tags: 2007, site-template

I am using SharePoint 2007. I have uploaded a custom site template (.stp) file on the site template library. When I created a sub site, my custom template shows up under the custom template tab. I choose my custom template and click "Create"... When it loads, it is not my template but a default SharePoint template. I am baffled why my custom site template isn't working.

Comment: were you sure that you didn't saved a default template.